# Why different results for Euler to Rotation Matrix in Matlab and Python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, rotation

When I use Matlab and Python to transform from Euler to Rotation Matrix, I get different results, and I can't figure out why.

`Python` code

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
cam_angle = 45
R.from_euler('xyz', [-90-cam_angle, 0, -90], degrees=True).as_matrix()
```

gives:

```
array([[ 0.        , -0.70710678,  0.70710678],
       [-1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.70710678, -0.70710678]])
```

While **Matlab** code

```
cam_angle = 45
eul2rotm(deg2rad([-90-cam_angle, 0, -90]),'xyz')
```

gives:

```
0.0000    1.0000         0
0.7071   -0.0000    0.7071
0.7071   -0.0000   -0.7071
```

Anyone have a idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Python code, use an uppercase `'XYZ'` for the `seq` argument for `from_euler` to use [intrinsic rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Conventions_by_intrinsic_rotations), which is the convention your MATLAB seems to be using. *(This convention will vary among MATLAB functions. See James Tursa's comment.)*

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
cam_angle = 45
R.from_euler('XYZ', [-90-cam_angle, 0, -90], degrees=True).as_matrix()
```

Result:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 0.70710678,  0.        , -0.70710678]])
```

From the [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler):

> Parameters: `seq` *string*
> Specifies sequence of axes for rotations. Up to 3
> characters belonging to the set {‘X’, ‘Y’, ‘Z’} for intrinsic
> rotations, or {‘x’, ‘y’, ‘z’} for extrinsic rotations. Extrinsic and
> intrinsic rotations cannot be mixed in one function call.

Comment: "... intrinsic rotations, which is what MATLAB uses." To be clear, this blanket statement is a bit misleading. MATLAB uses both conventions depending on which function is being called. E.g., Aerospace Toolbox and Robotics Toolbox use different conventions. So a eul2rotm(deg2rad([-90-cam_angle, 0, -90]),'xyz') call will produce a different result (transpose) from a quat2dcm(eul2quat(deg2rad([-90-cam_angle, 0, -90]),'xyz')) call because functions from toolboxes with different conventions are used.

Comment: The Robotics Toolbox (and others) use what MATLAB calls "point" convention, which matches what a lot of websites call "active", meaning you are rotating a vector. The Aerospace Toolbox (and others) use what MATLAB calls "frame" convention, which matches what a lot of websites call "passive", meaning you are rotating a coordinate frame. The quaternion( ) class in MATLAB can be configured to use either convention depending on whether you use the "point" or "frame" option. When doing conversions to/from direction cosine matrices, the dcm will be transposes of each other.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. What would be the equivalent extrinic function in Matlab?